# is it possible to select all columns as nvarchar or varchar without explicit casting in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

basically what I want is when i fill dataset executing some query, all data column must be  string only irrespective of type in database tables. Is it possible?

I want to know if any short SQL syntax exists instead of casting every columns when you have huge number of columns or even dynamic number of columns

Comment: why -1? it's valid question.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. If you select data from a table the data has the datatype of the column as defined. 
You can create a table with only nvarchar fields instead.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The database assumes that you defined your columns with a given type because you wanted them to be that type.  That's how the data was given to it to store, so that's how it's going to return it.  If you don't want them to be that type, the database requires you to explicitly state that.